# how to show "|" in table of .md file in github?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I had test
"&#124"
to express "|"
in my github page's  .md file 's table.
but failed.

It just show "&#124" but no symbol '|",

Could any one help?

I want to show "|" in the table of .md file on github page.
Much Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow &#124 with a semicolon. Here's the example below:

```
FirstName &#124; LastName | Phone | Email
--- | --- | ---
John &#124; Doe | 99658545 | jon.doe@example.com
```

I have tested on GitHub and it works. I would like to share my experience that initially it did not work because i entered it after a list item. Then I added a blank line by hitting enter just before that table. It worked !
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/organizing-information-with-tables), you need to escape the pipe (`|`) with a backslash (`\`):

> To include a pipe `|` as content within your cell, use a `\` before
>   the pipe:
>
> ```
> | Name     | Character |
> | ---      | ---       |
> | Backtick | `         |
> | Pipe     | \|        |
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML table tags to create a table in md file.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Waay easier this way